# How do I write a test for a class method that contains a while loop?

Tags: python, python-unittest

How can I test this method without getting an infinite loop?

```
def _check_for_pause(self):
    """Check if the game is paused and update pause time."""
    if self.ui_options.paused:
        pause_start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        while self.ui_options.paused:
            self.check_events()
            if not self.ui_options.paused:
                pause_end_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                self.pause_time += pause_end_time - pause_start_time
                break
```

In my other tests for methods that contain a while loop I used something like this to make the loop run only one time:

```
@mock.patch.object(Class, "class_attribute", new_callable=mock.PropertyMock)
def test_example(self, mock_class_attribute):
    mock_class_attribute.side_effect = [True, False]
```

But this worked only because I had class attributes inside the while loops.

In this case, the `self.ui_options.paused` is from another module and I can't modify the entire structure of the program just to make it a class attribute.

What options do I have?

I tried to mock the `self.ui_options.paused` variable but creating a side effect for it did nothing.

Comment: Seems like you could mock `self.check_events()` to set the `paused` attribute?  Or maybe mock the dependencies of *that* method (I assume it's looking for a UI event, which you could fake in your test) if you want your test to exercise both parts of your code?

Comment: Thank you so much mocking the `self.check_events()` solved my issue!